SwiftUI Dragging an Object in an Array by Gesture
In my model, I have an object which the user can drag around the screen.
struct ScreenElement: Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var offset = CGSize.zero
    var lastDragAmount = CGSize.zero
    
    func hash(into myhasher: inout Hasher) {
        myhasher.combine(id)
    }
}

The model holds an array of these objects:
@Observable
class DraggerModel {
    var screenElements: [ScreenElement] = []

func addScreenElement() {
    let newOne: ScreenElement = ScreenElement()
    screenElements.append(newOne)
}

In my View, I place the objects, and then track when the user drags on any one of them:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var theModel = DraggerModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(theModel.screenElements, id: \.self) { element in
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .frame(width: 200)
                    .offset(element.offset)
            
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { gesture in
                                print("new drag: \(element.id)")
                            }
                    )
            }

This works! When I drag on an object, I get a stream of printed output. But I want to actually move the object, so I add the following function:
// given an object, change its drag amount
func changeDragAmount(element: ScreenElement, theValue: DragGesture.Value) {
    for index in screenElements.indices {
        if screenElements[index].id == element.id {
            screenElements[index].offset = screenElements[index].lastDragAmount + theValue.translation
        }
    }
}

And I change the DragGesture function to call this function:
.gesture(
    DragGesture()
        .onChanged { gesture in
             print("new drag: \(element.id)")
             myModel.changeDragAmount(element: element, theValue: gesture)
                   }
        )

This technique (which works great when there is only one object, and it's not in an array), doesn't work in this case. I get a single Drag notification, and that's it.
I believe this is because in my changeDragAmount function, I am creating a whole new array each time (immutability!), and the new array isn't watching for, or isn't being informed of the subsequent Drag notifications.
What is a better way to do this? That works?

I would suggest making struct ScreenElement: Identifiable,... as well, and use @State private var theModel = DraggerModel() in your ContentView. Show a complete example of the code that actually represent your issue.

Thank you @workingdogsupportUkraine, I changed the name of the model so it matched (cut and paste error). But that is pretty much the entire code that causes the problem, I'm only missing some closing brackets here and there.

Try this approach using struct ScreenElement: Identifiable,
and the modified func changeDragAmount. Note also the ForEach(theModel.screenElements), no id: \.self.
Note, you will have to adjust the positioning (x,y) of the Circles to meet your requirements.
struct ScreenElement: Identifiable {  //<--- here
    let id = UUID()
    var offset = CGSize.zero
    var lastDragAmount = CGSize.zero
}

@Observable
class DraggerModel {
    // --- for testing
    var screenElements: [ScreenElement] = [ScreenElement(), ScreenElement(), ScreenElement()]
    
    func addScreenElement() {
        let newOne: ScreenElement = ScreenElement()
        screenElements.append(newOne)
    }
    
    func changeDragAmount(element: ScreenElement, theValue: DragGesture.Value) {
        for index in screenElements.indices {
            if screenElements[index].id == element.id {
                //--- here
                screenElements[index].offset = CGSize(width: screenElements[index].lastDragAmount.width + theValue.translation.width, height: screenElements[index].lastDragAmount.height + theValue.translation.height)  
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var theModel = DraggerModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(theModel.screenElements) { element in  //<--- here
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .frame(width: 50)
                    .offset(element.offset)
                
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture().onChanged { gesture in
                            theModel.changeDragAmount(element: element, theValue: gesture)
                        }
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}

EDIT-1:
An alternative approach to drag an array of Circles around the view is
using GeometryReader and a simple var position: CGPoint.
Note you don't need a @Observable class DraggerModel
for that, a simple @State private var screenElements: [ScreenElement] would suffice.
struct ScreenElement: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var position: CGPoint
}

@Observable
class DraggerModel {
    var screenElements: [ScreenElement] = [
        ScreenElement(position: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)),
        ScreenElement(position: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)),
        ScreenElement(position: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 250))
    ]
    
    func addScreenElement() {
        let newOne = ScreenElement(position: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
        screenElements.append(newOne)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var theModel = DraggerModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Add new") {
                theModel.addScreenElement()
            }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
            
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ForEach($theModel.screenElements) { $element in
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.red)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .position(element.position)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    element.position = value.location
                                }
                        )
                }
            }
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
        }
    }
}


Yes, the key here was using the Identifiable Protocol; with it, I didn't need to modify the changeDragAmount function. This led me to the subtle differences between Identifiable and Hashable, which I hadn't considered before - I had thought they could be interchangeble. And I like the GeometryReader idea, but my struct will be much more complex, so not this time. Thank you!
